# Fork GUI not building

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, monero-forks

Ok after successfully building the core I ve moved on to build the gui. But I faced a problem where the MSYS Mingw64 shell will suddenly crashhttps://github.com/honzapatCZ/nejcoin-guiIve changed the libwallet_api in the gui and root makefile of core to reflect my e:/programy/msys64 directory

Any help? please

I couldnt catch the error on the command line so there is video: https://youtu.be/ZFFfTXUjLf8

Answer (score 1):

`get_libwallet_api.sh` checks out the `v0.14.1.2` tag, your fork probably uses master. The commit that broke compilation is not included in `v0.14.1.2`.

Comment: Fixed by merging this [https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/5778](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/5778) , but I still dont get why is it not needed in the original repo.